# How to get less to output a css variable with quotes

Tags: css, less

I have a filter property that i want to get in quotes:

```
.TabClass{
progid: "DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=2)";
}
```

This is written in less like:

```
filter: e(%("progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=2)"));
```

When it is generated from less, there are no quotes for DXImageTransform, which causes a warning to be displayed in Safari dev tools.

How to ensure quotes are present?

Comment: Your filter is starting with a quote but is not closed with a quote

Comment: Thanks. that was a typo.

Comment: Is this the error? When you edited the question is impossible to view the problem. Don't edit the questions with the answers please.

Comment: Sorry if it is not clear.. what i meant is that the progid: is generated as progid: DxImageTransform... (without the quotes)

Comment: it's generated w/o quotes because your code explicitly asks for it - see [`e`](http://lesscss.org/functions/#string-functions-e) function (i.e. simply remove `e` call).

Comment: Thanks @seven-phases-max! Should have just read the documentation..but was trying to fix someone else's code :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution as @seven-phases-max pointed out was to not use the e function.